# Algebra (Not *)-Isomorphisms of von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, abstract-algebra, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be any two infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebras, they are operator algebras with operator composition as the multiplication and as infinite dimensional vector spaces they're isomorphic $F: A \rightarrow B$ right? I wanted to know if, or when are they isomorphic as algebras?? (Not necessarily *-isomorphic). That is, if they also satisfy

$F(ab) = F(a)F(b)$ ??

Answer (score 5):

No. This has more to do with simple/non simple algebras in general, than just with von Neumann algebras.

Denote $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded linear operator on the infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$. Then take
$$
A=B(H)\quad\mbox{and}\quad B=B(H)\oplus B(H)
$$
These are easily seen to be isomorphic as complex vector spaces. But not as complex algebras.

To see that, observe that $B$ has two non-trivial central idempotents $(\rm{Id},0)$ and $(0,\rm{Id})$, While the only central idempotents of $A$ are trivial, i.e. $0$ and $\rm{Id}$.

If you prefer, the center of $A$ is $\mathbb{C}I$ while the center of $B$ is $\mathbb{C}I\oplus\mathbb{C}I$. If there was an algebra isomorphism between $A$ and $B$, it would induce an isomorphism between their centers. And they are not isomorphic for obvious dimension reasons.

Comment: They are also isomorphic as Banach spaces by the Pełczyński decomposition method.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you, I was wondering, then is it possible for von Neumann algebras to be algebra-isomorphic then?