# A couple Hilbert space questions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I read in a [different post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359131/algebra-not-isomorphisms-of-von-neumann-algebras) that for a separable Hilbert space, it follows that $B(H)\oplus B(H) \cong B(H)$. However, I am not sure how to begin proving this.

If someone can provide a source or an idea for a proof, I'd really appreciate it.

Also on a separate note, I was wondering what a good source would be to learn about Hilbert-Schmidt and trace class operators between Hilbert spaces. Texts I have read usually cover operators in $B(H)$ but not in $B(H, K)$ in these contexts. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose $B(H) \oplus B(H) \simeq B(H)$ when $H$ is infinite dimensional and separable.  If $H$ were finite dimensional, then $B(H) \simeq \mathbb{R}^{d^{2}}$ while $B(H) \oplus B(H) \simeq \mathbb{R}^{2d^{2}}$.  In the separable infinite dimensional case, though, don't we have $H \oplus H \simeq H$ anyway?

Comment: $B(H)\oplus B(H) \cong B(H)$ ... isomorphism in what sense? Vector spaces (easy, with Axiom of Choice, both have Hamel dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$)? Algebras?  Banach spaces?  Banach algebras?  That other question says they are isomorphic as complex vector spaces, bur not as complex algebras.

Answer (score 0):

The argument for separable infinite dimensional case is quite simple.Using orthonormal bases it follows that all separable infinite dimensional are isomorphic.This result immediately gives what you want.

Comment: Unclear.  Your proof shows $H \oplus H \cong H$ but does not tell us about operators $B(H)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is never true that $B(H)\oplus B(H)\simeq B(H)$. At least, not as algebras.

This is a simple consequence of counting ideals:

- If $H$ is finite dimensional, $B(H)\oplus B(H)$ has two proper ideals, while $B(H)$ has none.
- If $H$ is infinite-dimensional and separable, $B(H)\oplus B(H)$ has 8 proper ideals, while $B(H)$ has only one.
- For non-separable $H$, it is at least obvious that they cannot be isomorphic as von Neumann algebras, because all ideals in $B(H)$ as sot-dense, while $B(H)\oplus B(H)$ has non-dense ideals.